# Using case expression inside where clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g

what I wanted is to add another condition using case statement or something.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tblcust 
WHERE cust_id = :p_cust_id 
CASE WHEN :p_first_name IS NOT NULL THEN
        AND first_name = :p_first_name
     WHEN :p_last_name IS NOT NULL THEN
        AND last_name = :p_last_name
     WHEN :p_first_name IS NULL AND :p_last_name IS NULL THEN
        NULL
     END;
```

Comment: Sigh... correct term is `case expression` as it evaluates to a single value (an expression), the entire select with all following clauses forms a `statement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not be able to use a `CASE` expression here to represent your logic, but it can certainly be reworded:

```
SELECT * FROM tblcust 
WHERE
    cust_id = :p_cust_id AND
    ((:p_first_name IS NOT NULL AND first_name = :p_first_name) OR
     (:p_last_name IS NOT NULL AND last_name = :p_last_name)    OR
     (:p_first_name IS NULL AND :p_last_name IS NULL));
```

But this is ugly, and we might able to use a `COALESCE` trick here to make it simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM tblcust 
WHERE
    cust_id = :p_cust_id AND
    (COALESCE(:p_first_name, first_name || ' ') = first_name) OR
     COALESCE(:p_last_name, last_name || ' ') = last_name) OR
     (:p_first_name IS NULL AND :p_last_name IS NULL));
```

The reason your `CASE` expression is structured incorrectly is because you are making it generate logical *expressions*, when it is only allowed to generate *values*.  But, in this case, we don't even need a `CASE` expression to handle your logic.

Comment: You can centainly do case in where Clause

Comment: thank you for the answer dude but what I also wanted is that when both first and last name are null then after the cust_id, the statement is done

Comment: @SurfaceTension Don't dude me if you don't know me :-)   ... I updated my answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know you now! Thank you so much <3

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I don't troll people, but say what I want to ;-P

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want logically , but you can do case inside a case like

```
With a 
as (
Select 1 id , NULL col1 union all
Select 2,10 union all
Select 3,Null
)
Select * from a
where id =1
OR  Case When col1 is not null then id=2
End
```

Comment: OP wants to have CASE statement in where clause and he is not talking about nested CASE.

Answer (score 0):

To make theses "mutually exclusive" sets of conditons use parentheses plus OR

```
SELECT * FROM tblcust 
WHERE (:p_first_name IS NOT NULL AND first_name = :p_first_name) 
OR (:p_last_name IS NOT NULL AND last_name = :p_last_name)
OR (:p_FIRST_name IS NULL AND :p_last_name IS NULL AND cust_id = :p_cust_id)
```

If there are still more conditions to add the be careful to contain all the sets within an "catch all" pair of parentheses